# Writing an int to a char array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm writing an emulator in C. Its memory is byte-addressible so I'm using a char array, but I need to read/write unaligned 32-bit integers.

Currently I'm using `*((unsigned int*) &memory[address])`, but it seems pretty horrible. What's the best way to do it?

Comment: Note that on some machine architectures, an unaligned 32-bit write like that won't work at all--rather than poor performance, you'll get a crash.  So depending on what your target platforms are, you may need to do the writes a byte at a time.

Comment: Also note that for some compilers, an `int` is not exactly 32 bits, so if you really mean "four bytes" rather than "sizeof(int)", and you care about portability and maintainability, you need to do something different.

Comment: To add one more thing to Kristopher's points.  If you want your emulator to be portable to both little and big endian platforms, the correct answer might be a little more complex still than just a `memcpy()` or other byte-wise copy that can deal with unaligned addresses. I don't know if this is important to you, but if it is it's something you need to think about.

Comment: I know about endianness but I don't think it matters much in this case. The emulator will only run in a specific environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `memcpy()` directly. For example:

```
unsigned int x = 10;
unsigned char* memory = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * 512);
address = sizeof(unsigned char) * 256;

memcpy(memory + address, &x, sizeof(unsigned int));
```

Comment: `memcpy()` is probably the safest way to go, portabilitywise, but if your compiler actually makes a function call every time, you may not be happy with the performance. (But note that many compilers will inline `memcpy` or replace it with a machine instruction.)